# Google Sheet - Automatically hiding rows based on a cell value instead of a row number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I created a custom menu in App Scripts with 3 sub-menus:

1. hide a specific set of rows
2. hide another set of rows
3. unhide everything

Basically, people can click on any of them for better visibility.
The issue with my current script is that if I put a filter, the rows won't be matching the ones I want to hide...

**Is there any ways to hide rows based on the value of one of the cell instead of row number?** So that no matter what data we are filtering, the needed rows will remain hidden.

Below the part of the code I believe I need to change:

```
function hideRowsC() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Keyword Report", hide: [3,7,20,25,37,43,49,53,57,60,68,77 ] }];
  sample_(obj);
}
```

My entire script below if it helps solving my issue.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom View')
    .addItem('Keywords Only', 'hideRowsC')
    .addItem('Categories Only', 'hideRowsK')
    .addItem('View all', 'showRows')
    .addToUi();
}

function showRows() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  showRowsInAllSheets_(sheets);
}

function hideRowsC() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Keyword Report", hide: [3,7,20,25,37,43,49,53,57,60,68,77 ] }];
  sample_(obj);
}

function hideRowsK() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Keyword Report", hide: [4,5,6,8,19,24,26,27,28,50,52,58,59,61,76,80,81,82 ] }];
  sample_(obj);
}

function sample_(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  showRowsInAllSheets_(sheets);
  const sheetObj = sheets.reduce((o, s) => (o[s.getSheetName()] = s, o), {});
  obj.forEach(({ sheetName, hide }) => {
    if (sheetObj[sheetName]) {
      hide.forEach(h => sheetObj[sheetName].hideRows(h, 1));
    }
  });
}

function showRowsInAllSheets_(sheets) {
  sheets.forEach(s => s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows()));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `Is there any ways to hide rows based on the value of one of the cell instead of row number?`, you want to hide rows by checking the value of the specific column.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the functions of `hideRowsC` and `sample_` are modified. About `const obj = [{ sheetName: "Keyword Report", checkCol: 1, checkValue: "sample" }]`, in this sample, it is checked whether the value of column "A" is `sample`. And, the rows that the value of column "A" is `sample` are hidden.

```js
function hideRowsC() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Keyword Report", checkCol: 1, checkValue: "sample" }];
  sample_(obj);
}

function sample_(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  showRowsInAllSheets_(sheets);
  const sheetObj = sheets.reduce((o, s) => (o[s.getSheetName()] = s, o), {});
  obj.forEach(({ sheetName, checkCol, checkValue }) => {
    const s = sheetObj[sheetName];
    if (s) {
      s.getRange(1, checkCol, s.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().forEach((e, i) => {
        if (e == checkValue) s.hideRows(i + 1, 1);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

- In your script, please modify `hideRowsK` as same as the above modification.

Comment: Hi Tanaike,

Thank you so much for your reply.
It seems that this is going to the right way!
However, for some reason the script is not functioning properly. If you have some time, would you mind having a look at it to see where the issue comes from ? link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fq4vWExk_xNBZwXEu9TIRWuKnFM4xvVtvv0EMJBokWM/edit#gid=0 and link to the script: https://script.google.com/home/projects/1j9BK4m-8e6jrNw867xMvBleHODkI0hl51_SjizbVKuoTMNxESrxJ9LXQ/edit

Comment: @Damien Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `However, for some reason the script is not functioning properly.`, when I saw your current script, it seems that you are not correctly using my proposed script. In my proposed script, `checkValue` is a string. But, in your script, `checkValue` is an array. This is the reason for your issue. If you wanted to change to your new specification, please modify `if (e == checkValue) s.hideRows(i + 1, 1);` to `if (checkValue.includes(e[0])) s.hideRows(i + 1, 1);` and test it again.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I realised I didn't use the modification as you suggested earlier.
Everything is working as it supposed to now. Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it.
Have a great week ahead !